# Invoice from multiple orders?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, data-structures

I need a way to create an invoice from **multiple orders** every month?

In the tbl_order table, I have a list of orders from the customer.

```
tbl_order table

OrderID (PK)
ShopID (FK)
CustomerID (FK)
Statu
Total
OrderDate
```

Let say I want to create an invoice for period: 1 to 31 May from `tbl_order.ShopID = 2`

(From there, I can an invoice report to a Shop/Company of Commission they owe me, etc. When I do recieved commission from them - I need a way to update invoice status)

The invoice should have Invoice Number and Invoice Date, in the invoice there will be multiple OrderID.

Do I need to create an invoice table, if so what the table design should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need 2 tables.

The invoice table.

```
InvoiceID (PK)
InvoiceDate
InvoicePrice
InvoiceBtw
ect. etc.
```

An link table between orders and invoices. 
So you can keep track which order is processed in which invoice.

```
InvoiceID (FK to tbl_invoices.InvoiceID)
OrderID (FK to tbl_orders.OrderID)
```

Comment: There should be OrderID (K) field in the invoice table? So it can have multiple rows of OrderID in the invoice table with same invoice number?

Comment: No information of the order should be in the invoice table, as the invoice has a one to more relation with the orders. The tbl_invoiceorders is used for that, which is the second table.

Comment: @user622378: The `OrderId` in the 2nd table is enough for this. No need to have it in the `Invoice` table as well.

Comment: So basically like this as example you mean? tbl_invoice(InvoiceID, InvoiceDate, InvoicePrice, etc) ... tbl_invoiceorder(invoiceorderID, OrderID(FK), etc)  or do you mean i should have InvoiceID(FK) in the tbl_order table?

Comment: Yes, my example could be used as starting point for your solution. It's up to you to decide which fields tbl_invoices should have though.

Comment: Thanks  Wesley van Opdorp. There is no need for  InvoiceID(KF) field in the tbl_order? so there is 3 tables. tbl_order, tbl_invoice, tbl_invoiceOrder ... ? I think I understood now

Comment: No there is not, the information is already available in the tbl_invoiceorders table, so storing it in the order table aswell would be double data in your database.

Comment: Ahh yes Wesley. Just last question. When customer placed an order on the frontend, should it automaically add into tbl_invoiceOrder as well? Or better to create invoice manually from the backend? How it should be.. Imagine having over 3000 invoices to every shop? What the best way to deal with this situation

Comment: Since you want to **generate** invoices on an monthly basis, I think you don't want to generate an invoice instantly - this would also destroy the one to more relation. You want to generate the invoices at a fixed time in the back-end for each shop. Which customer placed what order is not relevant.

Comment: @Wesley - One thing I came to mind is to generate invoices on an monthly basis using Cron Jobs ?

Comment: Yes - that would be an excellent choice. For example, you could generate the last months invoices the first monday of each month.

Comment: You could also create a stored procedure (you can name it `GenerateInvoices`) that creates invoices (adds required rows in tables `Invoice` and `InvoiceOrder` according to your rules, whichever these would be). Then you can call this SP any time you want, like 1st of every month or whenever.

Comment: ypercube, Im not sure what you mean for GenerateInvoices. Could you provide example of that? You can post answer. thank

Comment: Quick question, is it worth having TotalPrice field in invoice table? I was thinking Calulcate the cost from the OrderID's instead. Sometime there might be an error in one of the Order then TotalPrice have to be updated all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would require an invoice table.

The structure could be:

```
InvId (Autonumber) 
InvNumber (varchar (10))
InvOrderId (int(11))
InvStatus (int(11))
InvDateCreated (DateTime)
InvDateModified (DateTime)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. So for example, InvNumber will be the same number with mulitple rows of different InvOrderId number?  (1, 123, 4, 0, DATE, DATE) (2, 123, 5, 0, DATE, DATE) (3, 123, 6, 0, DATE, DATE)

Comment: Yes, but don't feel restricted by only numbers on an invoice.

Comment: I don't see where `InvOrderId` would help. The invoice would reference multiple orders. What couldl be added is `Year-Month` (where `2011-05` would be stored) or `ReferenceDateStart` and `ReferencesDateEnd` where `2011-05-01` and `2011-05-31` would be stored.

Comment: A field `ShopId` would be needed as well so we know which shop was invoiced.

Comment: Let say Invoice is paid (or completed), so I have to update every single rows of InvStatus with same InvNumber number?

Comment: to @ypercube, there will be multiple entries for the same invoice on this table each with the relevant InvOrderId. This is the most common way to know which orders relate to which invoice.

Comment: @Nightwolf: Yes, but you then should have 2 tables, like @Wesley's answer.

Comment: @user622378: yes, but in one line of code. e.g. `UPDATE tbl_invoice SET InvStatus = '3' WHERE InvNumber = '123'