# Invoice tables Design

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I want to know how to design invoice table.

An invoice include **many** orders from `order` table.

Is this invoices table is correctly designed?

**order**

- order_id (PK)
- User_id (FK)
- total_cost
- order_date
- status

**order_item**

- order_item_id (PK)
- order_id (FK)
- item_name
- cost

**invoice table**

- invoice_id (PK)
- invoice_no
- invoice_date
- period_start_date
- period_end_date
- status

**invoice_order** (an invoice with many orders)

- invoice_order_id (PK)
- invoice_id (FK)
- order_id (FK)

Is invoice_order table necessarry?

I could add invoice_id (FK) field in the order_table instead. The "order. invoice_id" would be updated when I have added a row in the invoice table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invoice from multiple orders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278061/invoice-from-multiple-orders)

Comment: I see too many `invoice design` questions the last days ...

Comment: @ypercube, It would save time if those darn instructors would post the question once, on behalf of all their students.

Comment: There's very little sense in building a system like this for real world use. I guess your purpose is purely educational. In that case I suggest you decide what you want to achieve and come up with a better spec for your hypothetical system.

Comment: @dportas Are you saying bad designed for real world use? My question was how to design tables for invoice can be linked to one or more orders.

Comment: I'm saying it's pointless because there are so many off-the-shelf accounting solutions available at a fraction of what it will cost you to build it. If it's a school project then pick a better project. If it's to run your business on then drop it and do something more productive instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the linking table. An order can be in mulitple invoices (if they didn't pay it!) and an invoice can contain many orders. In a linking table though I would not bother with •invoice_order_id (PK). The PK is a combination of the two FK fields. That guarantees uniqueness and since you are unlikely to have a child table of the link table, you really gain nothing by adding a surrogate key to it. Even if you did the performance difference between joining on two indexed int fields vice one would probably be negligible.

Answer (score 4):

You only need the `invoice_order` table if:

- An order can have one or more invoices

AND

- An invoice can be linked to one or more orders

By your suggestion at the end of your question, that's the case. You should not just have `invoice_id` and get it updated when a new invoice comes in, because you would lose the link between the order and the previous invoice.

**Update**

By the way, it's good that you have `cost` and `item_name` in order items, which is something beginners tend to find weird. You have to have those for historical reasons and to make possible to reprint the order with the same data, say, 3 years later, when the item might have had its name slightly changed and cost has surely been updated.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, which do you suggest I should do? An Invoice can have many orders but.. invoices can not have many same orders. (suggestion at the end of my question is not good solution?)

Comment: Does that mean an order can only be linked to one invoice? If so, why did you mention the `order.invoice_id` update?

Comment: sorry I meant An invoice can be one or more orders. So is it good to have invoice_order table ?

Comment: if an order can have one or more invoices AND an invoice can be linked to one or more orders, then Yes, it is

Answer (score 1):

Most invoices will have:

- Customer ID
- Sales Rep ID
- Payment Method
- Ship to Address
- Billing Address
- CheckBox:  Shipto same as billing
- etc.

Comment: OK.  Your question: Is this invoices table is correctly designed?  My Answer: No.

Answer (score 0):

Generalisation !! You should consider reducing that to 2 tables: Documents and DocDetails. Just add a DocType field in the Documents table, to differentiate Orders from Invoices.
If you need to track backorders, add a Link field to your DocDetails.
When you add an Order detail line, give the Link field the value of the table PK (counter).
When you add an invoice detail line, give the link the same value as the related order detail.

By the way, did not see any CustomerId in your tables !

Comment: That would be the most poorly performing solution. Generalization is usually a very bad idea in database design.

Comment: @hlgem: that's your opinion. I have successfull implementations using this scheme, and I know my suggestion is perfect.

Comment: @HLGEM: "Generalization is usually a very bad idea"... your sentence IS a bad generalisation, indeed.

Comment: @Idevelop, I said generalization is a poor idea in database design not that it is always a poor idea. Just because you made a poor design work doesn't mean it wouldn't have worked better if you had designed well. Maybe you should do some study on the internals of the databases you use and see why generalization is not optimum.

Comment: Several industry-leading ERP and accounting systems DO use generalisation tables with a common document number and common columns for invoices, credits, payments, journals, etc. If your financial documents have attributes in common then according to the Principle of Orthogonal Design you should have either a single table for them or have constraints to ensure the same tuples can't appear in more than one place.

Comment: @dportas: thank you. I'd like to point out that this generalisation makes it very easy to track Back Orders, and it IS perfectly representing a reality: orders and invoices are mostly identical documents (even if they have different roles). @HLGEM: And to close, the very basic level of the question and it's nature can let us suppose that the volumes involved will be far below performance concerns.

Comment: @dportas, I have used some of those COTS products and invariably they have performed badly and been a pain to query.